# Align all elements to point toward center

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hello I need to align the green arrow toward the center in Geo Nodes. I can not figure it out!
Please could someone help me.

I would like the green arrows to all point toward the center but I don't know how to do it. I have to align the normal of the center of the curve maybe?

These are curves with a profile extruded along the curve. I need the flat part to face toward the center

[image: how to make green align toward center?]

[image: Geo Nodes Set Up]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to grab some information from the icosphere **before** you convert it to curves.

It is easier to get the information you want at the beginning: you only need a couple nodes (**align euler to vector** + **normal node**).

[image]

In order to transfer the rotation of the normals of the input geometry you can use the **sample nearest** and **sample index** nodes (which are used to transfer attributes) to push the information along.  (I did not copy your tree exactly, not having your .blend):

[image]

You can make adjustments with the **rotate instances** node. Then when you instance at the ends of your profile curves, you can choose which side, in this diagram indicated by the green arrows, will point towards the centre.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may be similar to @common_goldfish's one - but since I saw the trouble investigating, I put it here also.

One thing I added is the 'Set Curve Normal' node and sampled a small centered icosphere's surface to get some normals. Could work for entirely spherical structure.

See if it helps:

[image]

[image]